# how do I correctly use Path (PyCharm)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, pathlib

I'm using PyCharm 2018.1.4

If I write

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('.')
```

this runs fine.

On the other hand, if I write

```
import pathlib
p = Path('.')
```

I get

```
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined
```

I thought by using *import pathlib* I'm importing the complete library, including *Path*.

Compared to a terminal session:

```
$ bpython
bpython version 0.17.1 on top of Python 3.6.4 /Users/fanta4/anaconda3/bin/python
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = Path('.')
>>>
```

no problem.

And just python:

```
Nick-iMac:~ fanta4$ which python
/Users/fanta4/anaconda3/bin/python

Nick-iMac:~ fanta4$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = Path('.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined
```

Where is the problem in PyCharm?
In PyCharm I see python 3.6 (File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a naked import (i.e. `import pathlib`), the `Path` class is not in the local namespace of your script. It is an *attribute* of the module object `pathlib`. To successfully access `Path` in this case, you must *explicitly* refer to it via its parent object. I.e.: `pathlib.Path`.

Also, I'm not familiar with `bpython`, but what you've described in your terminal session does not occur in `IPython`. In fact, I consider it extremely poor design that importing a library in *any* interactive environment implicitly imports all of its children objects. Number one, it risks polluting the namespace. Number two, it causes confusion in both new and old users of a language.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. And why is this then possible with `import os` ? Because I thought I can also just use `import pathlib`

Comment: @Nick As with `pathlib`, I would suggest that if you're using `import os`, and your interactive environment is importing everything *within* `os`, this is confusing. I would seriously suggest using a different environment if this is the case.